# CURL fail to send POST request with filestream

Tags: php, file, post, networking, curl

Trying to send filestream with other data to an API , but it return the error:

```
The video provided was null
```

Here is my code:

```
function create_video($files) {
    $api = "http://api.brightcove.com/services/post";

    $local_file_list = $files['file']['tmp_name'];

    foreach ($local_file_list as $local_file) {
        try {
            $fp = fopen($local_file, 'r');

            $ch = curl_init();

            if (FALSE === $ch) {
                throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
            }

            //"video":{"name":"test","shortDescription":"test","startDate":1432282741000,"endDate":null}
            $request = 'json={"params":{"encode_to":"MP4","create_multiple_renditions":"True","token":"' . WRITE_TOKEN . '"},"method":"create_video"}';

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($local_file));

            $content = curl_exec($ch);

            if (FALSE === $content) {
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
            }

            die(var_dump(json_decode($content)));

            return json_decode($content);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            trigger_error(sprintf('Curl failed with error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

> Few things need to note:
>
> 1. CURL does not return error , so it may not caused by CURL
> 2. The `filesize($local_file)` has return the correct file size
> 3. fopen($local_file, 'r'); return the stream type content, so the file is exist

How to fix that? Thanks

API reference:

https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/references/reference.html#Video_Write

**Update:**

Thanks for helping , but it now return another error:

```
POST methods require valid JSON-RPC in the POST body, with "method" and "params" properties
```

I have some idea of that as when I look at the request payload, it is slightly different from the correct one:

Current my version:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary8VABz8KuNRE8Hepd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"; filename="big_buck_bunny.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundary8VABz8KuNRE8Hepd--
```

The correct version

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCAB6WEANBJxoB3Op
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="JSONRPC"

{"params":{"video":{"name":"test","shortDescription":"test","startDate":1432282741000,"endDate":null},"encode_to":"MP4","create_multiple_renditions":"True","token":"VyocgALDnxU8HPvmnSnckgmXjoPlYWomc2La5Tn-evuAfsnSPJJoow.."},"method":"create_video"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryCAB6WEANBJxoB3Op
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filePath"; filename="big_buck_bunny.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryCAB6WEANBJxoB3Op

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="JSONView"

    {"params":{"video":{"name":"test","shortDescription":"test","startDate":1432282741000,"endDate":null},"encode_to":"MP4","create_multiple_renditions":"True","token":"VyocgALDnxU8HPvmnSnckgmXjoPlYWomc2La5Tn-evuAfsnSPJJoow.."},"method":"create_video"}
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryCAB6WEANBJxoB3Op--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the file to upload into [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) (PHP >= 5.5):

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($local_file, 'video/mp4', basename($local_file));
```

Then, add to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, making it part of the whole request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => $cfile,
    'JSONRPC' => '{"params":{"encode_to":"MP4","create_multiple_renditions":"True","token":"' . WRITE_TOKEN . '"},"method":"create_video"}';
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Before PHP 5.5 you can use the `@` to indicate a file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => "@$local_file",
    'JSONRPC' => '{"params":{"encode_to":"MP4","create_multiple_renditions":"True","token":"' . WRITE_TOKEN . '"},"method":"create_video"}';
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can I specfic 'video/*' instead of 'video/mp4' or I need to check the file type?

Comment: @user782104 You can leave it empty as well, but if you have a good idea of what it should be, use that. You shouldn't use wildcards.

Comment: 5.4.39 is the php version

Comment: @user782104 Sure, you can use `'file' => "@$local_file",` instead.

Comment: sorry but now there is another problem , please have a look if have spare time. Thanks

Comment: @user782104 Well, that's not a PHP issue anymore.

Comment: have updated the request payload, would you mind briefly tell a bit about how to structure like that? and "video" array can be ignore in the correct payload

Comment: @user782104 Perhaps you're not using the right naming? Try `JSONRPC` instead of `json`.

Comment: seems not make any difference when I change that , the request payload structure is still the same. Here is the website that correct send data: http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/samples/create_video.html#request

Comment: And this website has some hints? it use jsonrpc => 2.0, method=>...., parms=>{...} structure when calling the CURL

Comment: @user782104 So, perhaps the JSON is just wrongly formatted then? Why don't you use `json_encode()` anyway? Another thing you could try is to switch the order of the post fields.

Comment: Thanks , perharps I open another discussion